# How do I connect to two different servers using Perl's DBI module?

Tags: perl, dbi

I have to compare columns of tables located in two different databases in two different servers. So far, I know how to connect to one server & one database using Perl script. Is it possible to connect to two different servers using Perl's [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI) module? If so, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You connect to a database using `DBI->connect()`. This returns a handle to that database.  To connect to two databases, use two handles:

```
my $dbh1 = DBI->connect($connectstr1, $user1, $password1, 
    { PrintError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 });
my $dbh2 = DBI->connect($connectstr2, $user2, $password2, 
    { PrintError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 });
```

Now you can use `$dbh1` for the first database, and `$dbh2` for the second.